# api.hh.ru Параметр redirect_url : Что это такое?

Tags: python-3.x, api, hh.ru-api

Пишу скрипт на python для автоматизации рекрутинга с помощью API hh.ru: Простая выгрузка резюме в excel-файл.

Пожалуйста, подскажите что указать в параметр redirect_url при регистрации приложения на (https://dev.hh.ru)? В скрипте он никак не затрагивается. Можно ли формально ввести ссылку на свой телеграм или что-нибудь ещё?

Comment: Смотрите документацию: [Процесс авторизации](https://github.com/hhru/api/blob/master/docs/authorization_for_user.md#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Вкратце, redirect_uri - это адрес какого-то вашего веб-сервиса (доступного с компьютера пользователя), на который придет запрос после успешной авторизации. В параметрах редиректа будет указан временный код авторизации. Вот его нужно будет достать. Телеграм не подойдет, нужен именно веб-сервис. Ссылка на ваш телеграм не умеет обрабатывать произвольные HTTP запросы.

Comment: Хотя, если все самостоятельно делаете, можно `https://localhost` указать, после вашей авторизации откроется пустая страница, в адресе страницы будет `https://localhost?code=код_авторизации`, вот этот код потом в коде используете. Только у него ограниченное время действия, насколько я понял.